# How do I go abour proving 14x + 29y is always an integer if x and y are always integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to prove that $14x + 29y$ is always an integer, if $x$ and $y$ are both integers.

So far I've started by saying "assume $14x + 29y = n$, where $n$ is an element of an integer."

But I'm not sure where I'm supposed to go from there. I know I should probably use subsets somewhere in my proof but I'm not sure how.

Can I get some hints on how to start?

edit: I guess I should add the statement, ${14x + 29y : a,b \epsilon \Bbb Z}$

Comment: So I kind of explained my proof rather than solving it mathematically per se, but can anyone tell me if I'm doing it right?

Basically I said, 

An integer multiplied by another integer will always give another integer. Therefore 14x when x is an integer will always give an integer S. Similarly, 29y when y is an integer will always give an integer T.

An integer + integer = integer also, so if S and T are integers, $S + T : S,T \epsilon \Bbb Z$.

Since 14x = S and 29y= T, and $x,y \epsilon \Bbb Z$ is true, QED

Comment: Correct. It remains true if you replace "integer" by any subset S of integers so closed or, equivalentlu, any subgroup / ideal $\,d\Bbb Z,\,$ for which it suffices to test that S is closed under subtraction (subgroup test). Said more simply $\,d\mid x,y\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid 14x+29y.\,$ OP is special case $\,d=1.\ $

Answer (score 3):

Integers are closed with respect to addition and multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a formal proof from first principles, induction or its equivalent is unavoidable. So to prove for non-negative $x,y$, induct on $x+y$.

**Base Case** $x+y=0$

This means $x=0,y=0$ since $x,y \ge 0$. Now then, $14x+29y=0$ which is an integer, so the base case holds.

**Inductive Step**

Assume that whenever $x+y=m\ge 0$, you have $14x+29y$ an integer. Then, let $x+y=m+1$.

- If $x=0$, then $y > 0$ and so $x + (y-1) = m$ and $x$ and $y-1$ are non-negative integers. Thus, $14x + 29(y-1) = 14x + 29y - 29$ is an integer, say $p$. Hence,
  $$
  14x + 29y = p - 29
  $$
  which must be an integer as well.
- If $x > 0$, use a similar argument on $(x-1)+y$.

Now you can adapt it to cover the negative values for $x,y$...

Comment: See I always get confused on what that means, What does "induct on x + y" actually mean?

Comment: @J.Chang see update with an elaboration

Comment: Would the comment I made on my post work as a solution as well?

Comment: @J.Chang to prove that if $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $14x \in \mathbb{Z}$, you need induction anyway :-)